# Trying to apply to use && in if condition with range selection in value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi i am trying to apply if condition with && inside it between two condition

1. ```
   Convert.ToDouble(item["a"].ToString())==2.2
   ```
2. ```
   Convert.ToDouble(item["b"].ToString()) should be in range from 0.38 to 1.04.
   ```

I am trying like this

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(item["a"].ToString())==2.2 && NA)
```

NA--not getting idea how to apply range condition which is defined in point no 2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First store the result of `ToDoble` into a variable. Afterwards check if that value is greater `0.38` and smaller `1.04`:

```
var b = Convert.ToDouble(item["b"].ToString);
if(0.38 < b && b < 1.04) ...
```

Asside from that I´d strongly suggest to use `Double.TryParse`, which will return false if the inout is not a valid number. The methods from `Convert`-class throw an exception, if the string is not convertible.

Last: `double` is a floating-point number. Its very likely that your first condition will never be true, because the decimal number `2.2` cannot be represented as power of 2. To cirumvent that, you should allways compare for **ranges** when using floating-point numbers, e.g.:

```
var espilon = 0.0002;
if(Math.Abs(myValue - 2.2) < epslion)
    // great, do something
```